# gRPC comunication error stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR and SSL Wrong Version Number

Tags: nginx, ssl, grpc

Im trying to check gRPC service status from a grpcurl call, but got "SSL handshake failed due to WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER"

Logs from the Pod:
**"E0725 11:18:36.532479482      62 ssl_transport_security.cc:1455] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
"**

Im using an nginx ingress controler with a valid cert on this ingress

I0725 11:18:29.248298       7 controller.go:166] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0725 11:18:29.322648       7 controller.go:183] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0725 11:18:29.322834       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress", Name:"nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-xdlxz", UID:"4ad5159c-c2b7-4d0a-9a75-724f29f0d69c", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"13020298", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration

when send the grpcurl got this error
"**stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR**"

Not sure if the WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER is related to the fact I sending TLSv1.3 and the gRPC server does not support that or the certificate although it is valid, has some mistmach...

in case that helps, open ssl with show cert verification

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3277 bytes and written 440 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Comment: what gRPC language are you using?

Comment: gRPC language C++